# Projectile Vectors Speed

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors, physics, classical-mechanics

At time $t = 0$, a projectile of mass $m$ is launched from the origin at an angle $α$ to the
horizontal with speed $U$.
Let the position vector of the projectile be $\mathbf{r} = x\mathbf{i}+z\mathbf{k}$.

Determine an expression for the speed $v$ of the projectile at time $t$.

I have worked out already that $x = Ut\cos\alpha$ and $z = -\frac{1}{2}gt^2+Ut\sin \alpha$.

So, this means $\mathbf{r}=Ut\cos\alpha\mathbf{i}+(-\frac{1}{2}gt^2+Ut\sin \alpha)\mathbf{k}$.

Am I correct in differentiating $\mathbf{r}$ with respect to time $t$ and then calculating the magnitude using Pythagoras to calculate speed $u$? I am not sure whether I differentiated correctly:

$\mathbf{\dot{r}}=U\cos\alpha\mathbf{i}+(-gt+U\sin \alpha)\mathbf{k}$, So, $u = \sqrt{U^2 \cos{\alpha}^2+(-gt+U\sin \alpha)^2}$?

Comment: $\cos\alpha^2$ might be interpreted as $\cos(\alpha^2)$; the usual convention is to write either $(\cos\alpha)^2$ or $\cos^2\alpha.$ Other than that, your work looks fine. You can probably find some course notes from some university that give this formula, though perhaps with different symbols in place of $U$ and $\alpha.$

Comment: @DavidK Okay thanks for your help, I agree that my notation was unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David K answered your question, but for the sake of completeness, I am posting an answer.

As you can see from this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion#Velocity), your reasoning and computations are correct.